# Linux basics - automating a script execution

Tags: linux, bash

When beginning to work, I have to run several commands:

```
source work/tools
cd work/tool
source tool
setup_tool
```

Off course, doing this a few times a day is really annonying, so I tried to make a bash script `tool` where I put these commands and put it in `/user/bin` to run it with command

```
tool
```

However, there is a problem. When i run the script and then try to work by typing some of the tool-based commands, it does not work.
I figured out, that it is fine, since if I make a script and then run it, the script seems to run in the same terminal window, but what it really does is, that it behaves as if it created a "hidden window" for its execution and after termination of the script, the "hidden window" terminates too. So I am asking - is there a way to automatize the `source` command?

I have tried using `xterm -hold -e` command, but it runs the programmed script in the new window. Obviously, I don't want that. How can I achieve running it in the current window?

Comment: No need to touch anything in `/usr/bin`. It might be best to just define a function in your ~/.bashrc like: `mystart () { source work/tools; cd work/tool; source tool; setup_tool }`. Then the only thing you have to do is type `mystart` after sourcing this file.

Comment: Source your tool script! `. /path/to/tool` – as simple as that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't create a new hidden window, nor does it create a terminal. What happens is that if you're running a script, normally it runs on a new shell process. The script you're running is supposed to modify the shell environment, but if you're running the script in a new shell process, that shell process's environment is the one that gets modified, instead of your shell environment.

Scripts that needs to modify the current shell environments usually must be run with the `source` command. What you need to do is to run the script in the current shell. So you should do `source /path/to/tool`.

If you want to be able to source the script with just `tool`, put this in your alias file/shell startup (check your distro doc where the file is, but it's usually either .bash_aliases or .bashrc):

```
alias tool="source /path/to/tool"
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't put files like that in `/usr/bin`. As a general rule you don't want to mess with the distribution owned locations like that. You can use `/usr/local/bin` if you need a system-wide location or you can create a directory in your home directory to hold things like this that are for your own usage (and add that to the `$PATH`).

What you've noticed is that when run as a script on its own (`tool`,  `/path/to/tool`, etc.) that the script runs in its own shell session (nothing to do with terminal windows as-such) and you don't want that (as the changes the script makes don't persist to your current shell session).

What you want to do instead is "source"/run the script in your current session. Which you are already doing with that set of commands you listed (`source work/tools` is doing exactly that).

So instead of running `tool` or `/path/to/tool` instead use `source /path/to/tool` or `. /path/to/tool`.

As fedorqui correctly points out you don't even need a script for this anywhere as you can just make a shell function for this instead (in your normal shell startup files `.bashrc`, etc.) and then just run that function when you need to so that setup.

Be careful to use full paths for things when you do this though since you, presumably, want this to work no matter what directory you happen to be in when you run it.

Comment: Well, it is only copying, so I don't care, I am sure I am not messing with anything in /usr/bin, just adding. I made sure I was just adding and not rewriting, so I think it is fine.

Comment: Until some package wants to add a file with that name, sure. Or you forget that you put your custom file there and blow away `/usr` to reinstall and lose your file. etc. It just isn't a user/admin playground. There are places for that.